# VLOOKUP() Return 1st Non Null Or Non 0 Value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am using `VLOOKUP()` to return values, but am  hitting an issue where the 1st value may be `NULL` or `0`

How can I use this function (or a similar one) to return the 1st **NON** Null or 0 value?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(filterCon, Sheets("Ace Up Sleeve").Range("A:P"), 11, False)
```

Comment: The VLOOKUP formula only returns the first result found. You would have to use a different formula or the Find method for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be using the AGGREGATE worksheet function to accomplish this on a worksheet. Taking that into VBA, you can use `Application.Evaluate(...)` on the same formula.

```
Dim filterCon As String, fr As Variant, lr As Long, vreturn As Variant

filterCon = "findthis"

With Worksheets("Ace Up Sleeve")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    fr = Application.Evaluate("aggregate(15, 6, row(1:" & lr & ")/('Ace Up Sleeve'!K1:K" & lr & "<>0), 1)")
    If Not IsError(fr) Then
        vreturn = .Cells(fr, "K").Value
        Debug.Print vreturn
    End If
End With
```